# My SQL 5.6.4 DATETIME column milliseconds is not getting stored

Tags: mysql, mysql-5

Beginning from MySQL 5.6.4, milliseconds support is provided for date columns like `DATETIME` etc.

I just created a table to check if its working:

```
create table testdata(startime  DATETIME(5));
```

However, when I save some DATE(java.lang.Date) value using iBATIS framework it is ignoring milliseconds and storing:

```
2012-04-16 17:54:55.00000
```

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

When I use an SQL query like `INSERT INTO testdata VALUES ('2012-04-16 17:54:55.32345')` it stores milliseconds properly.  I want it to work via iBATIS.

Comment: Your problem is iBATIS, not MySQL. Perhaps better asked on StackOverflow?

Comment: MySQL 5.6 is not officially released yet. So it may be a problem from that side or from iBATIS side or from the way you are connecting these two.

Comment: You could also test with MariaDB 5.5 which is a GA release and has milliseconds support (since 5.2 version I think).

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue (both Hibernate and MyBatis don't store milliseconds) was solved by upgrading the MySQL driver from mysql-connector-java-5.1.17.jar to mysql-connector-java-5.1.26.jar.